# Regex for the string with '#'

Tags: regex

I wondering how should be the regex string for the string containig '#'

e.g.

```
abc#def#ghj#ijk
```

I wanna get

- #def
- #ghj
- #ijk

I tried `#[\S]+` but it selects the whole `#def#ghj#ijk` Any ideas ?

### Edit

The code below selects only `#Me` instead of `#MessageBox`. Why ?

```
var m = new RegExp('#[^\s#]+').exec('http://localhost/Lorem/10#MessageBox');

if (m != null) {
   var s = '';

   for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
     s = s + m[i] + "\n";
   }
}
```

### Edit 2

the double backslash solved that problem. `'#[^\\s#]+'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `#[^\s#]+` to match `#` followed by a sequence of one or mor characters which are neither `#` nor whitespace.

Comment: Someone ate your backslash. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript (this is JavaScript, right), but I guess that you should replace the whole `new RegExp('#[^\s#]+')` with `/#[^\s#]+/` or write `'#[^\\s#]+'` with a double backslash to actually include a backslash in the string this literal represents.

Comment: You're right, the double backslash solved that problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Match all characters that are not `#`:

```
#[^#]+
```